# How to propagate change event up the component hierarchy react.js?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am trying to create a number input field by extending the material-ui text field.. For this purpose, I need to validate the input values and stop the propagation for invalid values. I want the top container component to handle the change event if the input was valid. But, if I provide a event handler for the control it is not bubbling up to the container component. How can I achieve this ?

Here is my code -

My container component -

```
class ItemsContainer extends Component {

  handleItemChange(e)
  {
    console.log(e.target.value)
   //dispatch further redux action
  }

  render()
    {
      const cartTable = () =>  <ItemTable lines = { this.props.Lines } 
                       onItemChange = { this.handleItemChange.bind(this) } />
      return({cartTable })
    }
}
```

Stateless table component

```
const CartLineTable = ({
  lines,
  onItemChange = () => {},
}) => {
  let rows = cartLines.map((cl, k) =>  <NumberField
         id = { `${k}` }
          color = 'primary'
          defaultValue = { cl.value }
          onChange = { (e) => onItemChange(e, k, cl) }/>    )

return ( {rows })
}
```

Text control for number inputs

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import TextField from 'material-ui/TextField'

class NumberFieldBehavior extends React.Component {
  handleChange () {
    console.log('change fired!', arguments)
   //fire the parent components event handler ?
  }
}

class NumberField extends NumberFieldBehavior {
  render () {

    return(
        <TextField {...this.props} onChange = {this.handleChange.bind(this)}/>
    )
  }  
} 

export default NumberField
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add a `onChange` props to your `NumberField` Component and call the function passed to you when the `TextField`'s `onChange` gets called.

One possible implementation for bubble up:

```
class NumberField extends Component{
  onTextFieldChange(){
    //check condition for bubble up and then
    this.props.onChange(anyArgsYouWantToPass);
  }
  render(){
    return(
      <TextField {...this.props} onChange={this.onTextFieldChange.bind(this)}/>
    )
  }
}
```

and use it like this:
`<NumberField onChange={functionToCallOnValidChange}/>`

Comment: I am not able to pass extra arguments, any ideas ?

Comment: In the above example that I gave you, you can pass as many arguments as you want in call to `this.props.onChange(arg1,arg2,...)`

Comment: Those were not being passed, got it resolved by including them in the callback.